# Ubuntu Software - empty pages

Tags: software-center

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS several times. But Ubuntu software never worked.  I install via a USB-stick. As soon as Firefox is ready I activate VPN. Than I check "Ubuntu Software": Empty pages!  I tried some suggestions, I found in "Ask Ubuntu". No success! Now I installed "Synaptic Package Manager". Oh boy, that is complicated!
I like Ubuntu, but that U.-Software makes me to hate it.
Is there a way to get it run successfully?
Sincerely Heinzhorst

Comment: The Ubuntu Software Center has never worked flawlessly, it was always a problem and had issues.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Synaptic is good for package *management* but not for finding software names and such like the software center or such can do.

Comment: "*I tried some suggestions*" does not tell us what you tried, whether you did them correctly, or if the results include valuable troubleshooting information.

Comment: Sorry, I sent you 2 e-mails, but they didn't reach you, I found out later. The subject was already closed. After that I got a computer break down and I had to reinstall again.  But still Software doesn't  work. I will tray gnome-software. Thanks for remember me!

Comment: I tried all suggestions I could find in here and on internet, but no one was helpful. Mae I  ad here my returned e-mails  and ask you for further help again? I had to reinstall Ubuntu lately, maybe I need to make new tests per terminal to share the results here.

Answer (score 0):

You can install gnome-software instead it worked in my case just open terminal and type :

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!

Comment: Still got a problem with this side: How do I logout "ask Ubuntu"? Is there a button?

Comment: Your welcome, I don't know how to log out actually... Search it on internet

Comment: I am so unhappy. Gnome-software shows empty pages too today. It looks as bad as Ubuntu-software. I'd like to uninstall both software-packages. Are those lines correct?   "sudo apt uninstall gnome-software" and "sudo apt uninstall Ubuntu-software"

Comment: No thats sudo apt autoremove

Comment: Thank you. It worked for Gnom-software, but not for Ubuntu-software. I'd like to remove and reinstall that program. Because I have no working software-program I can't install nor remove in an easy way.

Comment: Maybe because that's a system app